# MySQL Sub Query Commands out of sync

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return a distinct list of hotel_country, hotel_resort and hotel_title and CHARACTER_LENGTH of each of these in the column next to it. I am doing something wrong as I am getting the error

```
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

This error is something I have not seen before and do not understand it. If I take the FROM and the WHERE out of the sub query data is returned, although I am not sure if this data is correct as it is not restricted.

In MySQL can you not use a FROM and WHERE in a subquery?

My MySQL is below - thanks in advance for help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT hotel_country, CHARACTER_LENGTH(hotel_country) as   hotel_country_length,

(SELECT DISTINCT hotel_resort
FROM client_x
WHERE item_status = 1) as hotel_resort,

(SELECT  CHARACTER_LENGTH(hotel_resort)
FROM client_x
WHERE item_status = 1
) as hotel_resort_length,

CHARACTER_LENGTH(hotel_country) + CHARACTER_LENGTH(hotel_resort) +
CHARACTER_LENGTH(hotel_title) as total_length

FROM client_x
WHERE item_status = 1
```

Thanks for marking this a duplicate although it is not.

I believe this is an issue with phpMyAdmin as when I run this through a terminal i get a different response

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They are totally different products.

Comment: CHARACTER_LENGTH neither looks like MySQL(lenght) or SQL Server (len) to me...maybe it is something else

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish putting select statements inside of a select statement where all information is coming from the same table?

Comment: @SQL.injection `CHARACTER_LENGTH()` is [a mysql function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_character-length)

Comment: @ypercube tanks, now we know it's mySQL

Comment: [Commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commands-out-of-sync.html)

Comment: Sorry you are right I am using MySql, also I have seen other questions similar but I do not understand where I am going wrong